# About Extension group in Category $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, weights

Let $M_I(\lambda)$ be the generalized Verma module with highest weight $\lambda$, $L(\lambda)$ be the simple highest weight module with highest weight $\lambda$.

Suppose $\mu\le \lambda\le \nu$, does this implies $\text{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}(M_I(\mu),L(\lambda))$ is a subspace of $\text{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}(M_I(\mu),L(\nu))$?